# How to effectively deploy MAAS server inside the KVM with 2 interfaces and bridge them with physical host server?

Tags: maas, kvm-virtualization

I have two servers on which I want to deploy MAAS and commission VM nodes. I don't have any physical small server with two interfaces (public and private), so I decided to deploy MAAS server inside the KVM.

I am unable to create two interfaces in MAAS KVM i.e., Private for the nodes and Public for the internet. Do i have to create two Virtual Networks in virt-manager for two interfaces of MAAS server KVM? How am I supposed to connect nodes(other VMs) with private network and expose them remotely?

I'm Stuck in this, it would be great if anyone could help me resolving these confusions?

Answer (score 0):

I just finished setting up a maas+juju cluster and while I'm waiting for some hardware, I did it all on a single machine inside KVM machines. It is a little involved and I'm probably going to write a blog at some point, but I'll try and get the gist of it here

The main thing to realise is MAAS "needs" 2 interfaces in order to

- connect to the internet
- manage the cluster of machines it connects to by self managing various services, the most important being DHCP+tftp for pxe boot

In the end, because I was having issues trying to bootstrap a juju controller inside a KVM machine with 2 nics, I ended up switching to a single interface for everything MAAS.

I just had to make sure I met the requirement of providing a network interface that:

- Had access to the internet
- Did not have any external DHCP (pretty sure this isn't a hard requirement, but it made things far easier)

To do that I created a KVM machine (but there's no reason you couldn't just use the host for this) to act as a gateway/router forwarding between 2 networks

- My external internet-facing, dhcp-enabled subnet
- A completely bare and unmanaged subnet (that MAAS now manages)

A great couple of resources for this are

- [How to enabled ip forwarding and turn a unix box into a gateway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222054/how-can-i-use-linux-as-a-gateway)
- [How to enabled port forwarding to expose a website](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables) (hint: the MAAS web ui)

Once this is setup, you can create a KVM with a single NIC bridged to the NIC connected to the unmanaged subnet and install MAAS on it.

Then connect all the machines you want MAAS to manage to the same unmanaged subnet and everything works perfectly.

Bonus, you be able to setup the gateway box as a firewall to your MAAS cluster.

I tried to cut back on many of the actually details, otherwise this would be an absolutely massive post. So feel free to ask clarifying questions if I left out too much detail.

Failsafe -

Comment: Hey thanks for help. Can you tell me how to PXE boot the maas node in kvm with the private/cloud lan of maas?  I am stucked in a problem i have configured maas server with 2 interfaces i.e one is public with br0 and other one is isolated virtual cloud lan (10.10.10.0/24) and enabled dhcp on it.  Now when i try to pxe boot my juju controller machine from private network it won't be able to get an image from MAAS server and says no bootable device.  can you help me resolving how to PXE boot kvm machine with maas? It would be great .. thanks in advance

Comment: So I could not get juju to deploy properly when I had 2 network interfaces in my MAAS KVM. I ended up creating a seperate gateway KVM that routed/NATed between my public and internal subnets, and then I only needed the internal subnet connected to my MAAS KVM. Let me know where in this list of steps you're running into issues

1. Can install MAAS inside a KVM with internet connectivity, through a bridge network
2. Have a private subnet that you enable DHCP (using MAAS)
3. Can compose a KVM machine in a pod using MAAS and commission and deploy it successfully
4. Can bootstrap juju

Comment: Its Number 3 in the list. I have created a juju KVM and configured it to only boot from a private NIC (10.10.10.0/24) having dhcp enabled i.e while i was creating a juju machine i configured it to boot from PXE instead of ROM. It is supposed to get an image from server and on maas server it should automatically enlist this new juju machine as a physical node and shoud automatically shuts off.. Now when i start that machine it won't get an image of ubuntu from maas server and stucks with an error "no bootable device". Do i need to configure machine or a maas server for PXE booting or what?

Comment: 1. I use maas to create the KVMs for me, look into setting up a KVM pod with maas 2. In order for your machine to pxe boot using maas, maas needs to be providing dhcp and tftp services on the NIC/subnet you're trying to boot from. - To enable dhcp, in mass goto subnets, select the untagged vlan of the subnet you want to boot from (in your case 10.10.10.0/24). The from the action drop down in the top right corner, choose enable dhcp. As long as the juju KVM has been setup using a network bridge to that subnet, you should now be able to pxe boot from maas. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was making a mistake of enabling DHCP on both the maas subnet and on a KVM private network that's why they conflicts with each other. I have disabled DHCP on Virtual Network and tried to boot direct from Maas Subnet and it works for me. I have already created a Pod for creating VMs from Maas. Thank you brother for your help

Comment: Now i have a confusion.. what do you suggest what would be the better way for installing OpenStack on KVMs?? From Juju or Conjure-up? And Should i make the individual machine for Juju_Controller or Bootstrap it with MaaS server and the make 6 KVM nodes for openstack and how much resources should i give to these nodes (i have a single power edge server with 24 cores and 48 GB ram with 1200gb hdd). And how am i supposed to integrate it with a MAAS server ?? I am a little bit confused at this point hope you could guide me on this .. and kindly make a detailed explanation if possible!  Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've been stuck at this point for a while. I only just got it working. I'm using juju (juju controller bootstrapped KVM using MAAS, though I precompose the KVM myself). (https://jujucharms.com/openstack-base) to install Openstack (needs a little configuration, most importantly 2 nics on the node with neutron gateway, which you'll have to manually add by editing the KVM xml as MAAS only creates 1 nic). I highly recommend (https://www.udemy.com/openstack-installation-and-deployment/) and follow the manual install. Will help you understand what's going on if you hit problems.

Comment: Also you should probably open a new question, seeing as this one is about MAAS, not openstack